# How to enable collapse/expand code blocks feature in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, coldfusion, eclipse-mars

I'm using the following version of eclipse on windows 7 desktop. On my ColdFusion files opened in eclipse I don't see +/- symbols for collapsing/expanding blocks of code. On the tool bar I can't find any option for enabling this feature. I don't see an option for Java-->Editor... either. In Preferences section I see only the options shown in the attached image:

Eclipse IDE for Java Developers
Version: Mars Release (4.5.0)
Build id: 20150621-1200

**UPDATE** Using the help from @E-Riz I found the folding option in Preferences and enabled all the options there as shown in the updated image below. But still I'm not seeing +/- symbols in the code editor to collapse/expand the code blocks. I've tried closing and reopening eclipse, as well.
[image]

As you can see there are no +/- sings in the file below although the editor used is CFEclipse:
[image]

Answer (score 3):

The feature is called *folding*. If you enter "folding" (without the quotes) in the Preferences search field, you'll find the places where it's configured.

I don't know if you have a plug-in specifically for editing ColdFusion files; if you do, it may or may not support folding. For example, [CFEclipse has folding support](http://cfeclipse.org/index.cfm/features/code-folding/), so if you open your files in that editor, you should see it.

Comment: Using your suggestion I found the "Folding" section and enabled all the options there as shown in new image in my original post above. But still I'm not seeing +/- symbols for collapse/expand in my code file. I'm using [Eclipse mars](https://www.eclipse.org/). Should I install CFEclipse instead?

Comment: According to your Preferences screen shot above, you already have CFEclipse installed. Are you sure your CF files are being opened in the CFEclipse editor when you double-click them?

Comment: I first open eclipse from the start menu: Eclipse-->Eclipse Java Mars. Then open a file from eclipse editor. Can you describe how I make sure the file is open in CFEclipse editor?

Comment: I have added another image that shows the file is opened in the CFEclipse editor but there are no +/- symbols in the code blocks for collapse/expand.

Comment: According to the CFEclipse page I linked to, it may only show the folding icons when the block is more than 3 lines. Your example file doesn't seem to have any such CF blocks.

Comment: I've updated the image 2 (in my post) that shows a file with blocks containing more than 3 lines. But still no folding icons. This is a file from Learncfinaweek\chapter1solution\admin\content\portfolio\editportfolio.cfm that I [downloaded from Learn CF in a week samples](http://www.learncfinaweek.com/week1/Installing_Sample_Files/).